# Command working in Command prompt but not working in Windows Terminal

Tags: command-line, terminal, windows-terminal

On restarting my PC today, few external commands(ssh, findstr) are not working in Windows Terminal. But they do work if I open up a command prompt.

In Windows Terminal I get

```
C:\>ssh
'ssh' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

On cmd prompt it works

```
C:\>ssh
usage: ssh [-46xYy] [-B bind_interface]
           [-b bind_address] [-c cipher_spec] [-D [bind_address:]port]
           [-E log_file] [-e escape_char] [-F configfile] [-I pkcs11]
           [-i identity_file] [-J [user@]host[:port]] [-L address]
```

That means I do have ssh.exe on my `PATH`

I have tried creating profile in Windows Terminal -

```
{
    ...
    "name": "remote-ssh",
    "commandline": "ssh user@host"
}
```

It works for ssh but I'd still want the these commands to work in Terminal.

Already updated to v1.12.10982.0

Adding [settings.json](https://pastebin.com/eKMeg0Vz) as requested. (personal identifiers removed)

Thanks

Comment: Please post the entire json file for your Windows Terminal profile

Comment: SSH works here in Terminal. 3 machines with Terminal.  You may need to Repair your Windows install.

Comment: Hi @Ramhound, I've added the file.

Comment: @John that's not really a option for me. Thanks though.

Comment: Why is Repair not an option?. I have used Repair Install many times.

Comment: It's my work computer. I don't have the privilege. I guess you can can this PC isn't really P :D

Comment: You should ask your employer to fix the computer so that terminal works.

Comment: “  "defaultProfile": "{00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000012345}" is incorrect since you don’t have a profile with the guid. Try deleting the file and relaunching Windows Terminal

Comment: Agree with @Ramhound, but I'd say "move it" if you feel better about that.  Everything in there should get regenerated with the defaults, which may fix your problem.

Comment: Hi, tried moving settings.json file and reinstalling Windows Terminal - None of it worked. But I noticed I'm still able to run ssh and other commands in PowerShell in Terminal, which is good enough for now. Thanks.